# How to dynamically change datepicker and restrict to different date ranges using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Datepicker library: gijgo

I'm trying to change the minDate inputs of the datepicker library depending on which option is selected by user is a drop-down menu. 
The options of the drop-down menu are as follows:

```
<select class='form-control mr-2' id='idType' name='idType' placeholder='Select' required>
  <option>UserID</option>
  <option>UID</option>
  <option>All Records</option>";
</select>
```

I am trying to **set the minDate of the datepicker to be 2 months from today if "All Records" is selected. Otherwise the minDate will be '2019-11-18'**. The datepicker is stuck on '2019-11-18' and will not change to 2 months prior with my if statement. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
   var pastMo = moment().subtract(2, 'M').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

   getDatePicker('2019-11-18', today);

   console.log(pastMo);

   $('#idType').change(function(){
     if($(this).val() == 'All Records'){
       $("#idSearch").prop("disabled", true);
       getDatePicker(pastMo, today);
     }
     else {
       $("#idSearch").prop("disabled", false);
       getDatePicker('2019-11-18', today);
     }
   });


function getDatePicker(min, today) {
  $('#start_datepicker').datepicker({uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',format: 'yyyy-mm-dd', minDate: min, maxDate: today});
  $('#end_datepicker').datepicker({uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',format: 'yyyy-mm-dd', minDate: min, maxDate: today});
}
```

Thank you for any tips or suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. You have to call this in the getDatePicker() function before setting the dates.

`$('#start_datepicker').datepicker('destroy');
 $('#end_datepicker').datepicker('destroy');`